# What is the best way to join more than one models to query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

What's the best way to write a query with more than one model?

I have made one model per table. I want to join all of those models to one query. what is the best way to do this in laravel?
I have heard about the repository but I have no idea about that.

Comment: Using ORM, let's say you have User & Profile (one to one relation) then create relation between Profile & User inside user model  ``protected $with = ['profile'];``  whenever you retrieve User you will have Profile as well without repeat  the query over & over

Comment: For complex join between multiple table, I suggest using Query builder. Please check the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins

Comment: This might be helpful https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-join-multiple-tables-with-eloquent-relationships

Comment: yahh. thanks for the responses. i will check those references one by one. thank you again